# Can We Use Extension of Scalars (Or Some Other Neat Way) to Prove This

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, modules

Let $k$ be a field and $b(x)$ be a polynomial of degree at least $1$ in $k[x]$.

Then for any given $f(x)\in k[x]$, there is an integer $m$ and polynomials $d_0(x), \ldots, d_m(x)\in k[x]$ such that the following hold:

> **1)** Each $d_j(x)$ is either $0$ or $\deg(d_j(x))<\deg b(x)$.
>   **2)** $f(x)=d_m(x)b(x)^m+\cdots + d_j(x)b(x)^j+\cdots +d_0(x)$

Of course, we can prove this using the Division Algorithm.

But I have a feeling that this should be doable by some module theory.

The polynomials $d_j(x)$ all have degrees strictly less than that of $b(x)$. So we can think of them as "reduced modulo $b(x)$". Thus I was tempted to say:

> The ring $k[x]$ is a $k[x]/(b(x))$-module with $\{1, b(x), b(x)^2, \ldots\}$ as a generating set.

Of course, this as such has no meaning because $k[x]$ does not have a $k[x]/(b(x))$-module structure.

But $k[x]$ is a $k[x]$-module and we may think of $k[x]/(b(x))\otimes_{k[x]} k[x]$ as a $k[x]/(b(x))$ module by extending the scalars via the natural map $\pi:k[x]\to k[x]/(b(x))$.

I don't know if this made the situation easier or more difficult.

Comment: This is analogous to the base-$k$ representation of a nonnegative integer. Being able to represent the nonnegative integers as $d_m k^m + d_{m-1} k^{m-1} + \cdots + d_0 k^0$ does not make $\mathbb Z$ into a $\mathbb Z/m$-module. It does have a homological interpretation in terms of extensions of $\mathbb Z/m$-modules (see http://www.math.wayne.edu/~isaksen/Expository/carrying.pdf ), and probably something like this works for polynomials as well, but it is hardly the easiest way to derive the result.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you for the insights and the link to the expository article.